# Remove sub-menu item from admin menu

Tags: categories

I created custom post type category that generated a 'Category' link on admin submenu. I want to hide/remove the 'Category' submenu under a custom post type.

This is the code I am using after searching on different forums, but its not working.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_remove_admin_submenus', 999 );
function custom_remove_admin_submenus() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category&post_type=poll' );
}
```

Can someone please help with it.

Thanks.